# How Do I Modify/Disable HOME Key Functionality in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, key

When I am viewing code in Visual Studio 2010, if a form/module/object tab is highlighted and I hit the HOME key, it takes me to the "home" tab (fartherest left tab). IMHO this is an awful short-cut. It removes you from the code you're looking at, and it took me a few times to do it to even know what I did to cause it. And to be clear, if I'm editing code, the HOME key will go to left-side of the line of code, and that's OK. It's the going to "home module" that's the problem.

Comment: Disabling the home key altogether would probably be an inconvenience though, wouldn't it? I know I use it often in the editor.

Comment: Of course. That's why I said Modify/Disable. I only want to disable the specific problem I'm discussing.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you mean by "a form/module/object tab is highlighted"... I tried using the WinForms Designer in VS2010 and can't manage to reproduce your issue.